# How to reset password in MariaDB on Windows?

Tags: mariadb

How to reset password in MariaDB? I use Windows and NOT Linux. Anyone who knows how to reset my MySQL MariaDB password? I tried to search on Google but did not help.

Answer (score 7):

I bumped into the same problem. I lost the root password for a test server on a windows development machine. 
Following the Linux step:

After

```
net stop mysql
```

Try invoking mysqld with

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

mysqld will only exit with a short message

```
[Note] mysqld.exe <...5.5.48.MariaDB> starting as process <pid> ...
```

then it quits. However I tried to launch mysqld directly, there is no mysqld.exe process. The service start command might have some argument combination that enabled mysqld to run. Tried to pass the settings through a configuration file and it works.

put

```
skip-grant-tables=TRUE
```

into MariaDB 5.5\data\my.ini
Restart mysqld, by

net stop mysql && net start mysql

then being able to login as root.

Don't forget to remove the inserted line and restart mysqld again.

Answer (score 7):

As this is top result in Google here's a quick way to change the password:

1. Stop the DB server
2. create a text file containing your new password:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'DontForgetMeAgain';
   ```
3. Run this command (don't forget to replace the path to file):

   ```
   mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\to\\file.txt
   ```

And we're done

Comment: Worked fine for me :-) Thx ! N.B. : at step 3, `mysqld`process then hangs, I have to kill him manually, but it does the job.  
But how is it that MariaDB loses the password ?...I had to repeatthe process several times in the past few weeks ....

Comment: in case anyone run into the error "mysqld is not recognized...", go the MariaDB installation folder first, then run the command. Mine is at `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.11\bin`.

Comment: On Windows 11, I got a warning while executing mysqld command.
Instead of mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\to\\file.txt
I had to use  .\mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\to\\file.txt
This command doesn't produce any output, so don't keep waiting, resume the DB server and try to login.

Answer (score 5):

Using skip-grant-tables led Maria Db to complain when changing a password even if logged in as root.
I had to do a little modification on Tom's answer in the content of the file to make it work for me:

After stopping the DBServer i created a file with this content:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mynewpassword');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then I run:

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin>mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\to\\file.txt
```

I then managed to log in